# Run command and keep editing it in Bash

Tags: bash, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

<kbd>return</kbd> runs command and clears the command line. Is it possible to skip the clear part? So the command is executed but command line and cursor position is preserved so you can keep editing it.

Alternative is to recall the command from history, but it is more keystrokes and looses cursor position

Comment: Is _cursor-up_ really that much too much?

Comment: @roaima if you are editing in the middle of the command line it takes more than just cursor-up to get back to the same position. Think tweaking options of the command in the middle of large pipeline

Comment: Fair point, but consider word-jumping sequences. I use `set -o vi` and I can jump about the line pretty quickly (although I can't get back to the previous cursor point trivially)

Comment: For a slightly different take on this, see https://github.com/sitaramc/notes/blob/master/try.webm.  The code is one line: `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND=echo fzf -q "$*" --preview-window=up:99% --preview="eval {q}"`.  The downside is (a) it executes the command on every change to the command line (i.e., every single character you type/delete), and (b) the output is limited to the preview window and *by default* can only be scrolled with the mouse, though you can bind that to some keys if you need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the builtin [`bind`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-bind) to get the current line buffer and evaluate it on a given shortcut, for example to bind on `ctrl + j`:

```
bind -x '"\C-j": eval "$READLINE_LINE"'
```

Just tested superficially, use it at your own risk ;)

The readline function [`operate-and-get-next`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands) is close to what you want but not exactly that.

Comment: Or `"\C-m"` instead of `"\C-j"`.

Comment: This works like a charm with recent Bash – thanks. Unfortunately `$READLINE_LINE` is not available in the ancient macOS Bash – but this is a different issue...

Comment: @Kamil well I actually picked the first shortcut that looked like useless to me. Is there a reason to prefer `ctrl+m`?

Comment: @MaxO Ah, too bad for the old bash versions... I don't have simple alternatives in mind unfortunately. Glad it helped even so.

Comment: `\C-m` *is* Enter. My way changes the *default* way you run commands. My impression was this was what the OP wanted.

Comment: Normally both `\C-m` and `\C-j` execute the command. Whichever one you bind, the other one will stay in case you want old behavior. Isn't this nice? I thought you knew about what `\C-j` normally does and had chosen it deliberately, not as "the first shortcut that looked like useless".

Comment: @Kamil Ok, got it. Not sure about the purpose of the OP but the difference is clear now to choose one or the other. Thanks.

Comment: yes I did notice the default action bound on `\C-j`, so let me correct it: "the first shortcut that looked like useless and roughly related to command evaluation" :p

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's assume you are using Bash, im not aware of such command line feature.
But on the other side, you can wrap your command line into a script and keep a second shell with an editor for editing the script, while using the first shell to run the script.
This way you won't loose your cursor and manipulate your command at will for debugging.

You can even tmux or screen to split your current shell in two having one part running the editor and second part running it, everything on the same window.

Answer (score 0):

This is available by default in Zsh with the <kbd>ESC-a</kbd> (<kbd>⌥-a</kbd>) keybinding – see `accept-and-hold` command